# OpenCV - How does it handle color profiles?

Tags: image-processing, colors, opencv, profile

I have a jpeg.  Its color profile is **sRGB**, of course.  I load it into "image" and call

```
cvCvtColor(image, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);
```

to convert it to grayscale.  When I step into that routine in the debugger, I find it multiplying pixels by these values:

```
#define cscGr_32f  0.299f
#define cscGg_32f  0.587f
#define cscGb_32f  0.114f
```

Waaaait a minute.  Those are the luminance values for **NTSC RGB**, not sRGB.  Furthermore, I cannot see that it's doing anything about **gamma correction**.  I am confused.  When OpenCV decodes the image, does it remove gamma correction and convert to NTSC RGB?

Bonus question:  Is there an OpenCV forum where the gurus hang?  I've googled in vain.

Comment: The OpenCV forum is https://forum.opencv.org/

Answer (score 1):

It ignores. OpenCV *usually* does not perform gamma correction. Well, [it does, only when `cvtColor`ing RGB-to-L*a*b*/L*u*v*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29854081/4510033) <sup>(But, how? Does OpenCV assume the gamma of the input image?)</sup>.