# Does OpenCV have functions to handle non-linearities in sRGB color space?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, colors, computer-vision

I am wondering whether OpenCV has functions to handle the non-linearities in the sRGB color space.

Say I want to convert an JPEG image from sRGB color space into XYZ color space. As specified in this [Wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRGB#Specification_of_the_transformation), one needs to first undo the nonlinearities to convert to linear RGB space, and then multiply with the 3x3 color transform matrix. However, I couldn't find any such discussions in the [cvtColor](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#cvtcolor) documentation. Did I miss something?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not explicitly stated in the documentation, so you're not missing anything, but OpenCV does **not** perform gamma correction in its `RGB2XYZ/BGR2XYZ` color conversions. You can confirm this by looking at the source code for `cvtColor` in

> `<OpenCV_dir>/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp`

If you look at the `RGB <-> XYZ` section you'll see that the input RGB values are simply multiplied by the coefficient matrix.

I have also not found any existing method to perform gamma correction on an RGB image.

Interestingly, a custom `RGB -> XYZ` conversion is done as a preliminary step for converting to both `L*a*b*` and `L*u*v*`, and in both cases it performs gamma correction.

Unfortunately, this isn't accessible from `RGB2XYZ` code, but you might be able to reuse it in your own code. I've also seen several code samples on the web, mostly using look-up tables for `CV_8U` depth images.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply, @beaker! It is surprising that OpenCV does not put these in the documentation and has inconsistent conversion for `RGB -> XYZ` and `RGB -> L*a*b*`. I submitted an [feature request](http://code.opencv.org/issues/4293) on the official website as well and hope it can be fixed in the future.

Comment: Did you already get an answer for this problem? Because I am facing the same problem.

Comment: @Sanchit There is still no built-in gamma correction for RGB2XYZ as of 3.1.0 (see http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/de/d25/imgproc_color_conversions.html#color_convert_rgb_xyz). You'll have to code your own, I'm afraid.

Comment: Yes, I have found that recently. MATLAB function (rgb2xyz or rgb2lab) does the gamma correction (or call it "linearization"). I think conversion process is not difficult once you know the format of the image (either linear RGB or sRGB). (MATLAB link: https://de.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/colorspaceconversion.html) (C implementation linear to nonlinear conversion and back http://svn.int64.org/viewvc/int64/colors/color.c?view=markup)

Comment: Now, there is another problem: how to know if the image (read by cv::imread(...)) function is either sRGB or Adobe RGB or linear RGB etc? I am confused.

Comment: I have found something interesting, in the "color.cpp" code provided by the OpenCV there is a method called initLabTabs(...) where gamma encoding and decoding has been performed. This method is always used before RGB2Lab, RGB2Luv and reverse. Moreover, in order to convert RGB to LAB color space, it first needs to be converted to XYZ space (note: this conversion is a linear process, i.e., matrix multiplication, therefore RGB value needs to be in linear space or linear RGB). I believe it does conversion from sRGB to linear RGB and then, linear RGB values are used to convert into XYZ color space.